# I need to clear the screen in Pygame, but the window reverts to it's original state once I let go of the button

Tags: python, pygame, fill

I have put what I believe to be the issue in italics. The button being pressed is 'start_rect' which is, of course, the start button. Trying to change the 'if' to a 'when' causes the game to freeze. Looked online, and there doesn't seem to be much regarding clearing when a button is pressed. Any way I can fix this?

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

boot = True
start = False
clear = False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750,450))
pygame.display.set_caption('Appalachia: Chapter 1')


title_font = pygame.font.Font('chapter1/Pixeltype.ttf',150)
sub_font = pygame.font.Font('chapter1/Pixeltype.ttf',80)


title_surface1 = title_font.render('x', True, 'white')
title_rect1 = title_surface1.get_rect(topleft = (125,60))

title_surface2 = sub_font.render('y', True, 'white')
title_rect2 = title_surface2.get_rect(topleft = (170,170))

start_surface = sub_font.render('z', True, 'white')
start_rect = start_surface.get_rect(topleft = (100,320))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.QUIT()
            exit
    if boot:
        screen.fill('black')
        screen.blit(title_surface1,title_rect1)
        screen.blit(title_surface2,title_rect2)
        screen.blit(start_surface,start_rect)

        *if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
         if start_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
          clear = True

        if clear:
         screen.fill ('black')
         clear = False*



    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Like I said, I tried switching 'if's to 'when's, but it just seized up after that.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57682263/how-to-completely-clear-pygame-window-with-button?rq=2

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the help of a commenter, I was able to repurpose some code for my own project. I needed to create a 'current_screen' variable that would only run once. The main menu was screen 1, and when the button was pressed it would take me to screen 2.